# what is problem in the following matlab codes

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
img=imread('img27.jpg');

%function rectangle=rect_test(img)

% edge detection

[gx,gy]=gradient(img); 

gx=abs(gx);
 gy=abs(gy);
g=gx+gy;

g=abs(g);

% make it 300x300

img=zeros(300);

s=size(g);

img(1:s(1),1:s(2))=g;

figure; 
imagesc((img));
 colormap(gray);
 title('Edge detection')


% take the dct of the image

IM=abs(dct2(img));
figure;
 imagesc((IM));
 colormap(gray); 
title('DCT')

% normalize

m=max(max(IM)); IM2=IM./m*100;

% get rid of the peak

size_IM2=size(IM2);
IM2(1:round(.05*size_IM2(1)),1:round(.05*size_IM2(2))) = 0;

% threshold
L=length( find(IM2>20)) ;


if( L > 60 )
   ret = 1;
else
   ret = 0;
end
```

Comment: You'll need to be a lot more specific - what's not working?

Comment: the function rectangle is not working

Comment: Not working how?  What have you done so far to debug it?

Answer (score 2):

I guess that the function doesn't work if you uncomment the line `function rectangle=rect_test(img)`. That is most likely because in your function, the variable `rectangle` is never defined. Probably you want to write `ret=rect_test(img)` instead.

Comment: That would probably do it. When debugging, try not to turn functions into scripts. That can become wildly confusing.